# adding js into body

Tags: 7, javascript

I use drupal 7 an I want to add very simple jquery code to only one page on my site.

```
 $('#var1').on('keypress keydown keyup', function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/([^\d]+)/, '')); 
});
 $('form').submit(


 function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
 var xyz = parseInt($('#var1').val());
$('#result').text("Result is " + ((xyz / 1.25)*30) + " days");
 });

 <form>
<input type="text" id="var1" />
<input type="submit" value="=" />
 </form>
 <span id="result"></span>
```

The problem is that pressing submit button allways reloads wlole page which I do not need. How to prevent this? Thank you.
I need it to work as smooth as this without reloading http://jsfiddle.net/eWXUT/3/

EDIT: I put the code on livesite but it is not working www(dot)vypadavanie(dot)net/ako-rychlo-rastu-vlasy?

In drupal 7 had to wrap the code inside jQuery(document).ready(function($) as well

Comment: Note, you can use the server side form api to show submitted and computed form data on the form

Comment: it will not work because you have javascript error in your page

Comment: drupal_add_js is a Drupal/PHP function not a javascript function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one solution for your problem

First solution add your javascript after the form or in the footer

```
 <form>
<input type="text" id="var1" />
<input type="submit" value="=" />
 </form>
 <span id="result"></span>

 <script>
 $('#var1').on('keypress keydown keyup', function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/([^\d]+)/, '')); 
 });

 $('form').submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var xyz = parseInt($('#var1').val());
   $('#result').text("Result is " + ((xyz / 1.25)*30) + " days");
 });
 </script>
```

Second solution add ready() handler like this

```
 <script>
 jQuery(function($) {
   $('#var1').on('keypress keydown keyup', function(){
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/([^\d]+)/, '')); 
   });

   $('form').submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var xyz = parseInt($('#var1').val());
     $('#result').text("Result is " + ((xyz / 1.25)*30) + " days");
   });
 ));
 </script>

 <form>
<input type="text" id="var1" />
<input type="submit" value="=" />
 </form>
 <span id="result"></span>
```

Third solution add your javascript code with ready() handler in `drupal_add_js` function

```
<?php drupal_add_js('/* javascript code */', 'inline'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a [drupal api for javascript](http://drupal.org/node/751744) and [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) is exactly what you are looking for..

Example:

```
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
```

As for stopping the page from refreshing, why not just add `action='#'` to your form

Comment: I tried to test your example but nothing shows. Should I put it in script tags?